# How to set date to nth day of this month when using Carbon of PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, php-carbon

From the [document page of Carbon library](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation), it is stated that it is possible to use simple words to initialize a Carbon object. For example, `Carbon::parse('first day of December 2008')` or `new Carbon('first day of December 2008')`

However, when I am trying to set the date to 10th of this month by the following trials

```
Carbon::parse('10th day of this month')
Carbon::parse('tenth day of this month')
Carbon::parse('10th of this month')
Carbon::parse('tenth of this month')
Carbon::parse('10 of this month')
Carbon::parse('ten of this month')
```

All of these fails.

Currently I am able to create my desired Carbon object by `Carbon::parse('first day of this month')->addDays(9)`, but the readability is not good. More code is needed to be read and it is very easy to mistaken as 9th of this month at the first glaze.

So, is there a way I can create the Carbon object with one parse only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, but this should work

```
Carbon::parse('10th ' . date('M'));
```